# Turn off eclipse confirm move

Tags: eclipse

One of the most annoying things about the new eclipse version is that it makes moving files rather hard.

By default on the left of your screen you will see the file system explorer (where it lists your workspace projects). I used to be able to drag folders/files around - but now each time I do that it pops up a window and asks me to select the destination folder. This is a problem because I already dropped the file to where I wanted it (often several levels away) and having to re-navigate in the pop-up to that same folder is a pain.

Can I disable the "Move Resources" confirm window somehow?

Comment: You may want to state exactly which "new Eclipse version" you are referring to.

Comment: +1 cause it would be good to know. However, i think thats wonderful i cant tell you how many times ive accidentially dragged and dropped a folder god knows where when i was trying to scroll the window while selecting multiple files/folders. For me this annoyance is welcome :-)

Comment: I don't see a version anywhere - but it happens with the last few builds I have been using. My most recent is build 20090920-1017.

Comment: I believe that's 3.5 - Galileo

Comment: Looks like just after 3.5.1, which is 200909170800 (http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.5.1-200909170800/index.php). Just above the build id, you should have a version number in the 'Help/About Eclipse SDK' Windows.

Comment: Just completed my answer with some PDT-specific bugs regarding resources and drag&drop.

Comment: Just reproduced the problem with a fresh PDT installation. (2.1.1 - v20090707-1108)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did not reproduced the issue either with the:

- Package Explorer
- Project Explorer

with a fresh Eclipse installation:

[image: http://web.archive.org/web/20130113130425/http://img697.i_mageshack.us/img697/5006/eclipsedragndrop.png]

Do you have any plugin installed? Do you reproduce the problem with  a clean installation?
Can you move some type of files (like `.txt` instead of `.java`) without any confirmation message popping up?
Are your files **read-only**? (which could prompt a confirmation message, as illustrated below)

[image: http://web.archive.org/web/20130113130425/http://img714.i_mageshack.us/img714/4746/eclipsedragndrop2.png]

---

Note: regarding PDT2.1 (and even the upcoming PDT 2.2 next July), the drag and drop or the move of resources [still has a lot of bugs](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?query_format=specific&order=relevance+desc&bug_status=__open__&product=PDT&content=move), including **[bug 256278](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=256278)** which concerns an odd message on a drag and drop:

[image: http://web.archive.org/web/20130113130426/http://img62.i_mageshack.us/img62/7362/eclipsepdtdnd.png]

I confirm this is PDT related (it would not happen with JDT)

[image: http://web.archive.org/web/20130113130425/http://img696.i_mageshack.us/img696/783/eclipsepdtmove.png]

[`org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.RefactoringWizardDialog2`](http://demo.spars.info/j/frameset.cgi?compo_id=141680&mode=frameset&ref=3&method=571&q=dialogpage&hl=dialogpage&CASE=0&MORPHO=1&LANG=1) is being called here. Every time a drag&drop is performed. And no preference seems to be there to cancel that behavior.

Comment: Same here. I was unable to reproduce the issue. Moved perfectly fine.

Comment: I am using Eclipse PDT on Ubuntu 64bit which might have something to do with it. I have NO other plugins installed. I'll try a freash install of PDT to see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: I am using the Project Explorer and when I get the prompt (not the one you mention though). If it was only a problem with read-only files I could fix that myself. BTW, nice screenshots!

Comment: Bummer. I hope they fix that *double-select-destination* bug soon. Thanks for all the work you put on this.

Comment: came here for the opposite: I'd like to have a confirmation dialoge when accidentally moving files/folders in the navigator, seems like vanilla eclipse doesnt have it :/